# How to replicate Google Analytics tracking code to run my functions

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to replicate the Google Analytics tracking code. The end goal is to fire various functions when the JavaScript code is done loading. How do I make the function run?

I've checked out this [link](http://code.iamkate.com/javascript/understanding-the-google-analytics-tracking-code/) so as to get a better understanding of how the code works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      (function() {
        window.MyAppContainer = "tc";
        if (!("tc" in window)) {
          window.tc = function() {
            window.tc.q.push(arguments);
          };
          window.tc.q = [];
        }
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src =
          "//myapi.forexample";
        script.async = true;
        var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
      })();

      tc("start", {
        email: "example@example.com"
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Loading the script directly i.e.

`<script src="https://myapi.forexample"></script>`

I am able to run my start function with the line

`MyAppContainer.start({email: "example@example.com" });`

How do I do the same using the Google Analytics Tracking code?

Comment: could you please clarify what exact functionality you need? does google analytics readyCallback would work for you? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#ready-callback

Comment: Yes, will the callback work for me? If not, any idea on how to implement it